# SQL table key value pairs to a XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a data table as follows

```
ID      Key     Value
--------------------------
1       F1      2
2       F2      5
3       F3      1
```

Using a TSQL in SQL server 2005, how can I convert this to a XML as

```
<Values>
  <F1>2</F1>
  <F2>5</F2>
  <F3>1</F3>
</Values>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, not even the arcane `for xml explicit` allows you to name XML tags based on a column.  If there are few different keys, you can work around that by enumerating them:

```
select  case when [key] = 'F1' then [value] end as [F1]
,       case when [key] = 'F2' then [value] end as [F2]
,       case when [key] = 'F3' then [value] end as [F3]
from    @t
for xml path(''), root('Values')
```

If there are many different keys, you could build the XML string manually:

```
declare @output varchar(max)
set @output = '<Values>'

select  @output = @output + 
            '<' + [key] + '>' + 
            CAST([value] as varchar(32)) + 
            '</' + [key] + '>'
from    @t

set @output = @output + '</Values>'

select @output
```

Test data:

```
declare @t table (id int, [key] varchar(3), value int)
insert @t values (1, 'F1', 2)
insert @t values (2, 'F2', 5)
insert @t values (3, 'F3', 1)
```

Both alternatives print:

```
<Values><F1>2</F1><F2>5</F2><F3>1</F3></Values>
```

Comment: This works great. I was trying it with "for xml explicit" but could not get through. Thanks this answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just query the table, store rows in array, and output them (to file or screen) using your (presumably server) scripting language?  If there is a way to get SqlServer to output like this I am not aware of it, but it should be pretty simple in pretty much any language.

Pseudo-code

```
LET arr = array of table rows
print "<Values>"
foreach in arr as row
  print "<" + row['Key'] + ">" + row['Value'] + "</" + row['Key'] + ">"
end foreach
print "</Values>"
```

Comment: I wanted to do it within a stored procedure without pulling data out. So this was not a good option to me. Thanks for answering.